# regex for this "001/Cnt.A/2021/EX.Dng" pattern

Tags: regex

I have some string like this below:

```
0015/Cnt.A/2021/EX. Mmj tech
021/Cnt.B/2021/EX.Mm logs
31/ Cgt.A / 2020 / PK Jap
453/ Nnt.A / 2020 / WK Jap pom sc
13/Wnt.A/2021/ LO.Mm pom
1911/Cno.A/2021/PQ Mm ris dMn
```

and I want to select for output like this below:

```
0015/Cnt.A/2021/EX. Mmj
021/Cnt.B/2021/EX.Mm
31/ Cgt.A / 2020 / PK Jap
453/ Nnt.A / 2020 / WK Jap
13/Wnt.A/2021/ LO.Mm
1911/Cno.A/2021/PQ Mm
```

I have tried this pattern `[0-9]{1,}\/[a-zA-Z.\s-]{1,}\/[0-9\s]{1,}\/[a-zA-Z\s]+[\.\s]+[a-zA-Z]{1,}` but it can't handle the 4th and 6th string. Anyone, can fix that pattern? and maybe make it more efficient?

edited:
There is a rule like this pattern -> `number/letter with dot or space/year/letter with dot or space`

Comment: Can you put in words what you intend? Remove everything starting at the second space after the last slash?

Comment: words after the slash are random, so I can't make it static in to the regex pattern

Comment: Do you just want to remove any words at the end of the string that start with a lowercase letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern to get all text up to the last slash and then only two words separated with a whitespace or `.` is

```
.*\/\s*[a-zA-Z]+[\s.]+[a-zA-Z]+
.*\/\s*\w+[\s.]+\w+
```

If you need to keep the initial regex part for stricter validation, use

```
[0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z.\s-]+\/[0-9\s]+\/\s*\w+[\s.]+\w+
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/zrROt5/3) (or [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/zrROt5/4)). *Details*:

- `.*\/` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more ASCII letters
- `[\s.]+` - one or more whitespaces/dots
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more ASCII letters.

`\w+` would match one or more letters, digits, or underscores.

Now, accommodating for the `number/letter with dot or space/year/letter with dot or space` rule:

```js
\d+\/\s*[a-zA-Z]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)*\s*\/\s*[0-9]{4}\s*\/\s*\w+[\s.]+\w+
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zrROt5/7). *Details*:

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `[a-zA-Z]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)*`
- `\s*\/\s*` - 0+ whitespaces, `/`, 0+ whitespaces
- `\d{4}` - four digits
- `\s*\/\s*` - 0+ whitespaces, `/`, 0+ whitespaces
- `\w+[\s.]+\w+` - one or more word chars, 1+ whitespaces/dots, 1+ word chars.

Comment: It perfectly works, but there is a rule like this pattern -> ```number/letter with dot or space/year/letter with dot or space```

Comment: @MicoS Alright, that is something you did not share at the beginning. So, you see I added your original regex prefix, so 1) `[a-zA-Z.\s-]+` (the second part) also matches hyphens, but it is not mentioned in your "rule", 2) can years contain just 2 digits? If they contain four digits, use `\s*[0-9]{4}\s*` instead of `[0-9\s]+`.

Comment: @MicoS I believe you can now fix your pattern, you've got all the necessary blocks/"bricks".

Comment: perfectly works with the rule, thank you!